# Best way for read and write a text file

Tags: delphi, file-io, text-files, lazarus, fpc

I am using the latest version of Lazarus IDE and I have a `Memo1` on my TForm1. I have to load a text file in `Memo1` and then edit every line of the Memo (I use `Memo1.Lines.Strings[i] := ...`). At the end I must save the edited memo at a particular path.

**Question**: I am looking for the faster way between:

1. Load the whole text inside the memo, edit its content and save into a new file (load all -> edit all -> write all)
2. Do a `while` loop (until the end of my `*.txt` file) that reads the file line by line, edit the content and save it in the new file. (load line -> edit -> write | load -> edit -> write | load line -> edit -> write | ...)

I am pretty new with Delphi developing, and I have also read some pages about `TStringLists`. My text file is going to have a lot of lines (It could have 5000+ lines) and I don't want that my program loses performance.

Any suggestion? Should I use `TStringList` or one of the two methods I listed before?

Comment: Are you editing (actually typing to modify the text) in the memo? If so, just load, edit and save. If not, just use a `TStringList` instead because you don't need the overhead of a GUI control.

Comment: The program has to edit every line adding some numbers at the end or at the beginning of the line. The user doesn't have to type anything.

Comment: Is it a little silly to load some data in GUI control and do nothing on GUI purpose? What do you think?

Comment: I am doing this because I have to see what the program does in the loop. I know what you mean, but this is only a "feature" I am testing for my program. Thanks for the advice anyways.

Comment: I do not think what reviewing thousands of text lines is really good way to test some operation. The real advice: ensure what you have `filesize * 2` bytes of free memory to take advantage of `TStrings` use, otherwise swapping will make it **much** slower than line-by-line.

Comment: definitely not a duplicate!

Comment: Inserting extra symbols into the middle of the strings forces  copying the rest of the text further and further in memory time and again, scaling as N^2. Faster code would be filling fresh new TStringBuilder (with memory pre-allocation) or Array Of String from the source data. However in this situation HDD read-write would be more limiting than RAM read-write anyway.

Comment: Also consider memo1.lines.beginupdate to make it faster

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`5000` lines isn't a lot, unless the strings are very long.

The easiest way is to use a `TStringList`. There's no need to use a GUI control unless the user needs to see or edit the content.

```
var
  SL: TStringList;
  i: Integer;
begin
  SL := TStringList.Create;
  try
    SL.LoadFromFile(YourFileNameHere);
    for i := 0 to SL.Count - 1 do
    begin
      SL[i] := IntToStr(i) + ' ' + SL[i];
      // Do any other processing
    end;

    SL.SaveToFile(YourFileNameHere);
  finally
    SL.Free;
  end;
end;
```

If (as you say in a comment above) you need to do this in a `TMemo` for testing purposes, you can do it the same way:

```
Memo1.Lines.LoadFromFile(YourFileNameHere);
for i := 0 to Memo1.Lines.Count - 1 do
  Memo1.Lines[i] := IntToStr(i) + ' ' + Memo1.Lines[i];
Memo1.Lines.SaveToFile(YourFileNameHere);
```

Of course, the easiest way to do this would be to write a procedure that accepts a plain `TStrings` descendent of any sort:

```
procedure AppendValueToStrings(const SL: TStrings; 
  StartingValue: Integer);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  Assert(Assigned(SL));  // Make sure a valid TStrings has been passed in
  for i := 0 to SL.Count - 1 do
  begin
    SL[i] := IntToStr(StartingValue) + ' ' + SL[i];
    Inc(StartingValue);
  end;
end;
```

Then you can call it with either one:

```
SL := TStringList.Create;
try
  SL.LoadFromFile(YourFileNameHere);
  AppendValueToStrings(SL, 10);
  SL.SaveToFile(YourFileNameHere);
finally
  SL.Free;
end;

Memo1.Lines.LoadFromFile(YourFileNameHere);
AppendValueToStrings(Memo1.Lines, 10);
Memo1.Lines.SaveToFile(YourFileNameHere);
```

Comment: Thank you, you solved my problem. Gonna accept. Just a question: I learnt that in a for loop you have to surround the code with a begin-end. Isn't it?

Comment: You don't *have to*, unless you have more than one line of code that is going to execute in the `for` loop. I usually do just as a habit in my own code, because I usually have more than one line that runs. If you're not sure, it's always better to use them. I'll edit to add them, though; it's a better habit to have.

Comment: Ok, so that code has only 1 line and I can omit the begin-end. Thank you again ;)